# Regex with substitution around a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem in some substitution in javascript (HTML).

I need to substitute ONLY the tags around every number, e.g.

```
<1>
```

become:

```
<sub>1</sub>
```

or

```
<20>
```

become

```
<sub>20</sub>
```

etc.

How can I do?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Use `<`, `>` and `\d+` to match the pattern `<digit/s>`, use capture groups `()` to extract the specific string from the text and use it in replacement as `$1`. Let me know if you face problems in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` and `regex` with groups to achieve this:

```js
var text = '<1>blabla<20>';
var newText = text.replace(/<(\d+)>/g, '<sub>$1</sub>');

console.log(newText);
```

Comment: True, @Tushar! Thanks for this! Just edited my answer

Comment: Thank you guys this works perfectly! :-)